# python split pandas numeric vector column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas, with a column which is a vector:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2], 'Averages':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]})`

[image: df]

and I wish to split and divide it into elements which would look like this:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2], 'A':[1,4], 'B':[2,5], 'C':[3,6]})`

[image]

I have tried 
`df['Averages'].astype(str).str.split(' ')` but with no luck. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
df[['A','B','C']] = pd.DataFrame(df.averages.values.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.concat([df['ID'], df['Averages'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).rename(columns = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'})
```

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the problem, as it returns a dataframe that does not include the 'ID' column.

Comment: @exp1orer Here:

    pd.concat([df['ID'], df['Averages'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).rename(columns = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'})

The essence of the problem was figuring out how to turn list-based data into multiple columns and my code solves that. You should know how to add a column in pandas and rename them. Not every answer on stackexchange should just be copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks, I'd recommend you edit your answer to include that! The OP provided a desired output, so your answer will be stronger if it produces that desired output. (Note that I'm not the OP, I came across your answer as an editor because it was recommended for deletion.)

Comment: @ exp1orer, thanks, updated